# Populating Google combo chart with multidimensional PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-visualization, json

I have a php array with data on students. It looks like this:

```
array(5) {
    ["question1"]=>
        array(30) {
            ["2014, 03, 02"]=>
                array(10) {
                    ["student1"]=>
                    int(54)
                    ["student2"]=>
                    int(43)
                    ... etc. ...
                    ["median"]=>
                    string(2) "49"
}
```

Each day the students answers five questions with a value from 1 to 100. Each day a median value for all answers to a single question is calculated. The answers and the median value is stored like above.

Now I want to populate a Google Charts combo chart with this data but I just can't get it to work.

I would like to visualise the data with the date on the X-axis, the 1-100 value on the Y-axis and each answer as a point. The data for the median value should be displayed as a curve over the points. Points and curves for each question should have its own colour.

But I'm pretty much stuck. I can't figure out how to insert the data. I have tried this approach:

```
var jsonData = (<?= json_encode($data)?>);
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);
```

but I only get the following error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Not an array    format+da,default+da,ui+da,corechart+da.I.js:181
lda    format+da,default+da,ui+da,corechart+da.I.js:181
Gp    format+da,default+da,ui+da,corechart+da.I.js:183
drawChart    ?side=graf:4888
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the format of your data.  The Visualization API expects data in a tabular format, where your x-axis data is in the first column and each data series (a set of colored points) is its own column of data.  You can either construct a json representation of a DataTable (for use with the `DataTable` constructor) or an array of arrays of data (for use with the `arrayToDataTable` function).

Since you are already using the `arrayToDataTable` function, this is the structure you need to have:

```
$data = array(
    array('Date', 'Question 1', array('type' => 'number', 'role' => 'interval', 'id' => 'Q1Median'), 'Question 2', array('type' => 'number', 'role' => 'interval', 'id' => 'Q2Median') /* repeat for other questions */),
    // format is array(date, q1 score, q1 median, q2 score, q2 median...)
    // set the median in the first row for the day, leave it null for all other rows
    array('2014, 03, 02', 54, 49, /* repeat for other questions */),
    array('2014, 03, 02', 43, null, /* repeat for other questions */),
    // repeat one row for each student for each day
);
```

The median values are set in an "interval" role column, which you can style to display as a curved line in the chart options:

```
interval: {
    // use the column ID of an interval to set the options for that interval
    Q1median: {
        style: 'line'
    },
    Q2median: {
        style: 'line'
    }
    // etc...
}
```

Options for styling intervals are documented [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/intervals).